# Selenium mitmproxy

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, mitmproxy

I am trying to use mitmproxy to capture traffic generated by a python script using Selenium. My script manages to pass my requests through the proxy but the traffic doesn't look the way I would expect (see below). My script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


def main():

    options = Options()
    options.accept_untrusted_certs = True
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    myProxy = "0.0.0.0:8080"
    options.proxy = Proxy({
        'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
        'httpProxy': myProxy,
        'sslProxy': myProxy,
        'noProxy': ''
    })
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

    driver.get('http://example.com')

    driver.quit()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

To observe the response generated by the above script, I am using mitmdump with the following script:

```
from mitmproxy import ctx

def response(flow):
    print(flow.response.data.content)
```

Which produces the following output:

> 127.0.0.1:35966: clientconnect
> b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff}TMs\xdb \x10\xbd\xfbWl\xd5K2#$'i\x1a\x8f-i\xfa\x99i\x0fi\x0fi\x0f=\x12\xb1\xb2\x98\x08P\x01\xc9\xf6t\xf2\xdf\xbbB\x8e#7\x99\x9a\x91\x81]x\xbb\xef\xb1\x90\xbd\x12\xa6\xf4\xbb\x16\xa1\xf6\xaa)f\xd9c\x87\\x143\xa0_\xe6\xa5o\xb0\xf8\xbc\xe5\xaam\x10>\x19\xc5\xa5\xce\xd2\xd1:\x1b\x97(\xf4\x1c\xca\x9a[\x87>\x8f:*\xb1E\x04i1q\xd6\xde\xb7\x0c\x7fw\xb2\xcf\xa3\x8fF{\xd4\x9e\ra#(\xc7Y\x1ey\xdc\xfat\x08\xbf:@\xbd\x84\xa4\xb9\xc2<\xea%nZc\xfdd\xffF\n*\xe7\x02{Y"\x0b\x93\x18\xa4\x96^\xf2\x86\xb9\x927\x98\x9f=A9\xbf#2C\x06\xfb\xc0\xa5s\xd1\xe8\xbb3b\x07\x7f\xc20Lyy\xbf\xb6\xa6\xd3\x82\x95\xa61v\t\xaf\xab9\xb5\xf3\xd5a\x89\xe2v-\xf5\x12\xe6O\xa6\x96\x0b!\xf5\xfa\xc8VQ\xa6\xac\xe2J6\xbb%0\xde\x92\x9c\xcc\xed\x9cG\x15\xc3\xd8\xb3N\xc6\xf0\xa1\x91\xfa\xfe\x86\x97\xb7\xc1tM\x9bb\x88nqm\x10~~\x8dh\xfc\xbdE\r\xb7\\xbba\xf2\x05\x9b\x1e\xbd,9|\xc3\x0e\xc9r0\xc4\xf0\xde\x12w\xc2\xa6\xa5\xcc\xa1\x95\xd5S.a\xf0\x10\xfe\x85\xec't\x83pKx;\x9f\xb7\xdb\xe7\x0c/Q\x01\xef\xbcy\x81\xe89\xaa\xd5\x7fE\x13\xd4&\x19\xdc\x19+\xd02\xcb\x85\xec\x1c\xe9\x94\\x1e\x01\x98-s5\x17fC\xc8\xed\x16.\xe8\xbb\xa2o\x18\xdb\xf5\x1d\x99\xc7\xa1%\xf3\xf3\xd3\xd5\x84\x0c_\x0e\xea\xc5\xd4\xf7\xd2I\x8fbB\xed1\x93\x8b\xc5\x9b\xc5b\x92\xc9p\xfeL`i,\xf7\xd2\x10Km4NA\xdf)\x14\x92\xc3\x89\xe2[\xb6\xd7\xe7j\xd0\xe7t\x02~\xac\xe2QU\xfc\xa3\xd8D\xe5c\xc7\xc3$d\x96\x86\n-\xc2Ye\xe9x\x1dg\xd9P\x9bt;)\xd8\xbe\x8e\xeb\xb3g7\x93L\xa3\xaf-~\xd4\xd2\x81\x08v\xa0Qe,t\x0ea\x985M\xe7\xfc@\xb8G\xc0\x11\xc1\r\x0ez\x0e:E\xf7\xc9%\xf0\xcbtDb\x17\xb6xB\x1a\xabe\x8f\xa6\xa1!y\t\xa0\xb3Ht|m:\x0f\xad\x95\x14\xa24t\xb4R\x071\x81\xe6\xdc\xddS\x85\x84\xe8-Z%\x9d#G\x92\xa5\xed!\xcf\x8c\x1e\x08\x8bU\x1e\r\xcf\x84[\xa6\xe9f\xb3I$\xd7<1v\x9d\x8e!]\xbaO3*n\x8c\x1dH\x10\xa0\nA\x92\x84\xd0x\x11\x10\xb34\x88\x93\xa5{\xa9\xd2\xf1A\xfb\x0b(\xeb|o\xe8\x04\x00\x00'
> 127.0.0.1:35956: GET http://example.com/
> << 200 OK 648b

The **flow.response.data.content** appears to be encrypted. Confusingly, if I simply run mitmproxy (not mitmdump) and open the corresponding flow I can observe the unencrypted response in the interactive UI. Also, when I make this request via the curl command:

```
curl --proxy http://0.0.0.0:8080 https://example.com
```

I get the unencrypted traffic to display through both mitmproxy and mitmdump as I had expected. It is only through selenium + mitmdump that I encounter this issue.

I have added the mitmproxy certificate to my firefox profile and to my system to no avail.

Comment: Firefox has automatically changed the request to https. If you want to capture http requests you need to disable the Firefox option to upgrade all requests to https. Also TLS decryption doesn't seem to work. Which versions of mitmproxy and Firefox do you use?

Comment: I am using Firefox version 99 and mitmproxy 4.0.4 (bad omen lol). Is it not enough to have selenium trust all certificates to get past the https issue? My understanding is that Firefox only actually makes SSL connection to mitmproxy then mitmproxy goes out and handles the rest.

Comment: If my understanding is correct - shouldn't mitmproxy have the information required to decrypt the encrypted https traffic?

Comment: I an not sure if the `accept_untrusted_certs` option you set is still effective. You should better install the mitmproxy root CA certificate into the Firefox trusted certificate store (or on Windows into the Windows cert store, AFAIK Firefox on Windows also trust certs in the Windows store). A problem may arise because if I remember correctly Selenium uses a separate Firefox profile. Also the used mitmproxy version is heavily outdated. Install latest version and delete the `~/.mitmproxy` directly to force recreation of root-CA cert.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've reinstalled mitmproxy as the latest version and I've added the certificate from mitm.it to my firefox profile (as well as to my system). Some earlier error messages relating to tls handshakes have disappeared and I can see unencrypted responses inside the interactive mitmdump.

However, I still only see encrypted traffic when trying to use mitmdump. When I apply a script i.e. "mitmdump -s script.py" to access the "flow.response.data.content" the content is still encrypted. I don't know how I can decrypt it.

Comment: Are you sure the data is encrypted and not just compressed? HTTP response can be compressed using gzip, bzip, brotli(br) and other compression algorithms. Check the response headers for content encoding.

Comment: You are correct. I had no idea that http responses got compressed. The encoding indicates that is compressed with gzip and I am able to decompress it to retrieve the correct output. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you print `flow.response.data.content` (`.data` is not a public API, see [the docs](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/api/mitmproxy/http.html#Message.content)). If you'd use `flow.response.content` instead, mitmproxy should decompress the contents automatically:

```py
def response(flow):
    print(flow.response.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not one of encryption but of encoding. Looking at the **flow.response.data.headers** it is revealed that the response has gzip encoding. Using the following script with mitmdump:

```
from mitmproxy import ctx
import zlib

def response(flow):

    try:
        content = zlib.decompress(flow.response.data.content, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    except:
        content = flow.response.data.content

    print(content)
```

Correctly decode the data to print the expected result. In a more robust script we can decide how to decode the data by reading the encoding from the header.